# Temboard: when monitoring a server modifying postgresql.conf on the server is not effective?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I've installed the Temboard tool (http://temboard.io/) to start monitoring my postgresql server. I've noticed that when I modify the postgresql.conf on the server and I restart it, the change is not taken into consideration. If I do it in the Temboard terminal it is. Is it normal? I was supposing that temboard should follow what is done in the postgresql.conf if I modify it on the server. Where temboard agent manages the server config?

Answer (score 0):

Temboard presumably uses [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html), which on the server side, writes into `postgresql.auto.conf`.

The contents of `postgresql.auto.conf` takes precedence over the contents of `postgresql.conf`, so if a setting is specified with both methods, the value in `postgresql.conf` is going to be ignored, no matter how you restart.

To get back to the situation where the setting in `postgresql.conf` is not ignored, consider doing

```
 ALTER SYSTEM RESET setting_name;
```

Then the next reload or restart should pick up the value from `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Brilliant, by chance is there a link on the net where this is explained in more details?

Comment: @jeanpierrehuart: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html explains the configuration and the override mechanism in reasonable detail.